# Extremely slow writing to external USB disk

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, debian-wheezy, usb

I have measured the transfer on the following disk to be 2.75MB/s:

```
iManufacturer           2 Seagate
iProduct                3 BUP Slim SL
```

The interface is USB2 so it should be fastered than that:

```
bcdUSB               2.10
```

I've done:

```
hdparm -W1 /dev/sdd
mount /dev/sdd1 -o data=writeback,barrier=0 /mnt/c
```

I'm copying Debian 7 VM files to it so there's quite a number of small files. Still.

What are the reasons for this? How do I improve on that?

Host OS: Debian 7.11.

Comment: Upgrade to a currently supported Debian release?

Comment: Hi, is it a usb hdd with an external power adapter ? can you test the speed with a usb stick ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: that's saving the data before the upgrade to a currently supported Debian release.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the hard drive to a USB 3.0 port if available. The [specs](https://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/product-content/seagate-slim-fam/seagate-slim-portable-drive-usm/en-us/docs/slim-portable-usm-data-sheet-ds1760-1-1209-amer.pdf) for the slim drives support usb 3.0 which is much faster.  A transfer speed of 2mb/s is normal for usb 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to format the disk with appropriate filesystem and then try to copy, sometime too many writes slow usb's, also you can try to change block size based on type of file you can copy it may improve your copy speed.